# AES128 encryption on iOS without loading entire NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes

Using samples from Apple Dev library (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html), 
in particular this method 
`- (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)plainText key:(NSData *)symmetricKey context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt padding:(CCOptions *)pkcs7 { return nil; }`

I can decrypt and encrypt files by reading them to NSData and then passing to this method.

however, this has an unfortunate consequence of me having to use a lot of RAM for this process.

Is there any way to decrypt the file right on disk without loading the file to NSData?

Comment: What is the problem with using a lot of RAM? Is there not enough? How large is the data?

Comment: @Zaph, I need to encrypt 800 mb files, and do 4 at the same time. No, there is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the individual Common Crypto routines: `CCCrytorCreate()`, `CCCryptorUpdate()`, `CCCryptorFinal()`, and `CCCryptorRelease()` repeating `CCCryptorUpdate()` for each chunk.

See Mike Ash's [Friday](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-08-10-a-tour-of-commoncrypto.html) on *A Tour of CommonCrypto*.